# javascript accessing advanced JSON object arrays

Tags: javascript, html

This is the .json data that i get from my localhost:

```
[
  {
    "option" : {
      "GroupID" : "2",
      "OptionsID" : "1",
      "group_name" : "Select two:",
      "items" : [
        {
          "item" : {
            "OptionItemID" : "1",
            "item_name" : "item 1"
          }
        },
        {
          "item" : {
            "OptionItemID" : "2",
            "item_name" : "item 2"
          }
        },
        {
          "item" : {
            "OptionItemID" : "3",
            "item_name" : "item 3"
          }
        },
        {
          "item" : {
            "OptionItemID" : "4",
            "item_name" : "item 4"
          }
        },
        {
          "item" : {
            "OptionItemID" : "5",
            "item_name" : "item 5"
          }
        },
        {
          "item" : {
            "OptionItemID" : "6",
            "item_name" : "item 6"
          }
        },
        {
          "item" : {
            "OptionItemID" : "7",
            "item_name" : "item 7"
          }
        },
        {
          "item" : {
            "OptionItemID" : "8",
            "item_name" : "item 8"
          }
        },
        {
          "item" : {
            "OptionItemID" : "9",
            "item_name" : "item 9"
          }
        },
        {
          "item" : {
            "OptionItemID" : "10",
            "item_name" : "item 10"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

In my HTML file in my script tags I'm using `.getJSON(url,function(data){}`. During that function I have a `.each` loop inside each other to call and gather the information but it doesn't seem to be running.

So my questions:

- How do I iterate through an array of objects and within that array of objects another set of array objects?
  hat do I use to iterate through an array of objects and within that array of objects another set of array objects?
- Is `.each` an efficient way to iterate through the elements? (and if so could someone help me with that.)

Comment: object.option.items.forEach(function(item){ console.log(item); });

Comment: Welcome to SO. To get an answer, (1) be more specific on what you want. (2) Ask a question. --I didn't understand what your problem is.

Comment: `During that function i have a .each loop inside each other to call and gather the information but it doesn't seem to be running.` Why not post that code?

Comment: Jonathan -- there are people who have looked at this question, and are willing to spend time thinking about this in order to help you. However, if you don't give all the information (such as the code that you need help with), you wind up not only making it impossible to help, but actually wasting people's time. Please include all the details -- no need to be vague.

Answer (score 0):

The following will iterate through the items in that JSON object(I am using the variable test for the JSON object) displaying each item attributes optionItemID.

```
var iter;
for(iter = 0; iter < test[0]['option']['items'].length; iter++)
{
    console.log(test[0]['option']['items'][iter]['item'].OptionItemID);
}
```

Comment: This is weird. No reason not to initiate the `iter` variable inline: `for(var iter = 0;...`. If you're going to put anything outside the for block, it would be the maximum: `var max = item.length; for (var iter = 0; iter < max; iter++)`

Comment: honestly I always do it the way you have it but Douglas Crockford says its not a good idea because in JS the scope of the variable is not limited to the for block when you declare it in the loop conditions.

Comment: So what? let the variable live till the end of the function. Code readability is much more important this case... (and probably any other case)

Comment: Crockford also advises not using `++` operators, using dot notation, and a space after `for`. "Crockford said" is not a good reason to make weird code, especially if you're not following his advice in a majority of the code! :) Plus, the way you have it there does the exact same thing with the `iter` variable -- it pollutes the entire scope. You can put the scope of the max in the declaration: `for (var iter = 0, max = items.length;...` Check this out for a reason why you should do it that way: http://jsfiddle.net/wVMZB/

Comment: Yes it pollutes the scope however the reason for keeping it out the loop condition is that it makes it apparent hat the scope is polluted.  Listen if I hadn't done it that way, people would have complained about that..since I did it this way people are complaining that I did it this way.

Comment: I find it curious that an experts opinion in the language we are currently discussing means nothing...